# Ayuda con robots.txt para bloquear patrones de URL

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Necesito ayuda para escribir un robots.txt para bloquear los siguientes patrones de URL:

```
http://www.server.com/1234/12/
http://www.server.com/5645/22/
```

El primer conjunto de números puede variar pero siempre son 4 dígitos, el segundo son dos dígitos cualquiera.

Puede darse el caso de algunas URL parecidas a estas:

```
http://www.server.com/1234/12/page.html
http://www.server.com/1234/1212/page.html
http://www.server.com/1234/12/img/page.html
```

Estas no deberían bloquearse.

Por ahora es intentado algo como esto, pero no estoy seguro si funciona:

```
Disallow: /*/*/$
Disallow: /1234/*/$
```

Comment: El problema del robots.txt es que no todos los buscadores y herramientas indexadoras lo respetan (yo creo que en vez de proteger exponen las rutas delicadas que declaras ahí). Esto tal vez te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859399/block-google-robots-for-urls-containing-a-certain-word  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033367/blocking-urls-that-contain-numbers-in-robots-txt Tal vez podrías configurar tu htaccess o el archivo de configuración de tu servidor web para hacerlo